# execute function from option select in Angular

Tags: angular

How can I execute this function from the option of a select? I am working with ngFor to iterate each option, but depending on each selection you must execute the function.

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let categoria of categoriasTest | async">{{ categoria.nombre }}</option>
</select>
```

from a button I did it this way:

```
(click)="filtrarData(categoria.nombre)"
```

My function

```
filtrarData(categoria: Categoria) {
  this.avisosTest = this.fs.filterBy(categoria);
  this.selectedCategoria = categoria;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngModelChange** with ngModel on **`select`** on selection changed.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedcat" (ngModelChange)="filtrarData()">
  <option *ngFor="let categoria of categoriasTest | async">{{ categoria.nombre }}</option>
</select>
```

and in TS

```
filtrarData() {
 //DO WHATEVER WITH this.selectedcat;
}
```

Comment: `Error: Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined.` I made a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-filter for a better understanding. What I want to do is the same effect as the buttons but with a select.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it stayed like this and it worked for me:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCategoria" (ngModelChange)="filtrarData(selectedCategoria)">
   <option *ngFor="let categoria of categoriasTest | async" >{{ categoria.nombre }}</option>
</select>
```

Review stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-filter